# How to EXEC sp_OAMethod inside EXEC (@sql)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Inside my stored procedure I defined the following piece:

```
SET @table = 'table_name'
SET @column = 'table_column'
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @table WHERE @column LIKE @filter) > 0
BEGIN
  SELECT TOP (1) @email = @column FROM @table WHERE @column LIKE @filter
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @object, 'Replace', @result OUT, @email, @employeeNewEmail
  UPDATE TOP (1) @table SET @column = @result WHERE @column LIKE @filter
END
```

This needs to be done on a number of tables, so I wanted to wrap WHILE statement into a dynamic sql query

```
SET @query =
'WHILE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM '+@table+' WHERE '+@column+' LIKE '+@filter+') > 0
BEGIN
  SELECT TOP (1) '+@email+' = '+@column+' FROM '+@table+' WHERE '+@column+' LIKE '+@filter+'
  EXEC sp_OAMethod '+@object+', ''Replace'', '+@result+' OUT, '+@email+', '+@employeeNewEmail+'
  UPDATE TOP (1) '+@table+' SET '+@column+' = '+@result+' WHERE '+@column+' LIKE '+@filter+'
END'
```

and then simply

```
SET @table = 'table_name'
SET @column = 'table_column'
EXEC (@query)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and I'm always getting an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ', ' to data type int.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @table = 'table_name'
SET @column = 'table_column'

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM '+@table+' WHERE '+@column+' LIKE '+@filter+') > 0
BEGIN
    SET @query ='SELECT TOP (1) '+@email+' = '+@column+' FROM '+@table+' WHERE '+@column+' LIKE '+@filter+'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod '+@object+', ''Replace'', '+@result+' OUT, '+@email+', '+@employeeNewEmail+'
    UPDATE TOP (1) '+@table+' SET '+@column+' = '+@result+' WHERE '+@column+' LIKE '+@filter+''
    exec(@query)
END
```